# Powershell script works but also gives an error message

Tags: windows, powershell

The error is as follows:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Across.ps1:6 char:21
+ $result.Handle.Close <<<< ()
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Close:String) [],
RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The script is as follows:

```
# Load ntuser.dat
reg load HKU\Across C:\users\Default\NTUSER.DAT

# Create a new key, close the handle, and trigger garbage collection
$result = New-Item -Path
'Registry::HKEY_USERS\Across\Software\AcrossStuff'
$result.Handle.Close()
[gc]::Collect()

#Unload ntuser.dat
reg unload HKU\Across
```

Can you please help me fix this.
Thanks!

Comment: I can't believe that's the only error you get. You should get an error that `-Path` is not set before that one. The registry-path has to be on the same line as `-Path`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$result` seems to be null, check the place where it is assigned and ensure that this is not null

Answer (score 0):

It is either your script is not properly lined up or path does not exist. You have to check this.

```
$result = New-Item -Path 'Registry::HKEY_USERS\Across\Software\AcrossStuff'
```